# Split a TypeScript declaration file with nested namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Suppose I have the following ambient type declaration:

```
// index.d.ts
declare namespace admin {
  namespace auth {
    function doSomething();
  }
}
```

I can consume this as follows:

```
// caller.ts
import * as admin from './index';

admin.auth.doSomething();
```

Is there a way to split the  d.ts file into two with no impact on the caller? Ideally I'd like to move the nested namespace `auth` to its own file auth.d.ts.

Answer (score 1):

Following seems to work:

```
// index.d.ts
import auth as _auth from './auth';

declare namesapce admin {
  export import auth = _auth;
}
```

Then in another file:

```
// auth.d.ts
export namespace auth {
  function doSomething();
}
```